# Why does my ajax request not work with hidden AJAX form inputs CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, ajax, forms, cakephp, input

For some reason my ajax form does not work if I change my form elements to hidden. It does how ever work if i change them to inputs instead. Why would that be?

## Here is the view

```
<div id="price">
        <?php
        $this->Js->get('#phonepricearea');
        echo $this->Form->create('offer', array('url' => '/PhoneKarma/PhoneQueries/ajaxOffer', 'class' => 'custom'));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('phoneCapacity',array('value'=>''));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('phoneCondition',array('value'=>''));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('carrier',array('value'=>''));
        echo $this->Js->submit('Check', array('class' => 'button expand',
            'title' => 'Check',
            'url' => array(
                'action' => 'ajaxOffer'
            ),
            'update' => '#price'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?></div>
```

## Controller

```
    public function ajaxOffer($capacity=null, $condition = null , $carrier = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data) && $this->request->is('ajax')) {
       //do stuff this doesn't effect the code..
        $this->render('ajaxOffer', 'ajax');
        } else {
         $this->set('offer', "0");
        }
    }
```

## Javascript to change Value

```
$('#offerPhoneCapacity').val(id);
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the application with firebug or Google chrome developer tools?

Comment: Yes Its giving me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: Post your ajax and controller functions

Comment: That's a really strange URL to be using with CakePHP.  Are your routes tweaked to allow that?

Comment: Yes, its a plugin that is why. The page does not give any error when i visit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 errors are usually [security component blackholes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks). The documentation says it would issue 404 errors, but that's wrong, [it throws a `BadRequestException`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.3/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php#L335) if not configured otherwise.

> If an action is restricted by the Security Component it is black-holed
>   as an invalid request which will result in a 404 error by default. You
>   can configure this behavior by setting the
>   `$this->Security->blackHoleCallback` property to a callback function in
>   the controller.
>
> `SecurityComponent::blackHole(object $controller, string $error)`
>
> Black-hole an invalid request with a 404 error or a custom callback.
>   With no callback, the request will be exited. If a controller callback
>   is set to SecurityComponent::blackHoleCallback, it will be called and
>   passed any error information.

Your problem is probably caused by the security components [form tampering prevention](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention) functionality. Hidden fields need to be static, because their values are used to genereate the security token, if the values change, the genereated comparision token will be different and thus the form will be treated as invalid.

> By default SecurityComponent prevents users from tampering with forms.
>   It does this by working with FormHelper and tracking which files are
>   in a form. It also keeps track of the values of hidden input elements.
>   All of this data is combined and turned into a hash. When a form is
>   submitted, SecurityComponent will use the POST data to build the same
>   structure and compare the hash.

If you need to change hidden fields, then you have to define them in the [`unlockedFields` property/option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent%3a%3a%24unlockedFields) or by using the form helpers [`unlockField()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#working-with-securitycomponent) method.

Examples (untested):

```
public $components = array
(
    'Security' => array
    (
        'unlockedFields' => array
        (
            'Offer.phoneCapacity',
            'Offer.phoneCondition',
            'Offer.carrier'
        )
    )
);


public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Security->unlockedFields => array
    (
        'Offer.phoneCapacity',
        'Offer.phoneCondition',
        'Offer.carrier'
    );
}


$this->Form->unlockField('Offer.phoneCapacity');
$this->Form->unlockField('Offer.phoneCondition');
$this->Form->unlockField('Offer.carrier');
```